# Is it safe to rely on session variables to store information to be shared between multiple asynchronous flows?

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have a couple of flows that rely on session variables that are generated in one flow and then passed to the other.  Is it safe to rely on session variables used by two asynchronous flows?  I guess I don't fully understand the scope of 'sessionVars' in a mule application or in a given mule message.

Comment: How do you invoke the other flows? With `flow-ref` or VM queues?

Comment: VM queues.  What's the difference?

Comment: VM queues prevent you from using flowVars and would complicate in/out properties, so session is indeed your best bet here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mule session has nothing to do with the Java EE session that is shared across threads. The mule session is part of the MuleMessage and how they works is explained [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Concepts), therefor if you want to share something across multiple flows processing the same message that is the way to go.

If instead you are looking into a way to store a value from a flow processing the message **A** and pick that value from a flow processing the message **B** you should consider store this value into the [objectstore](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Object+Stores)

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that session variables are returned to http endpoints that are request-response. This could expose sensitive data. I am trying to locate the original mention and official mitigation strategy but have yet to locate it again.

But an easy solution is to remove them at return point of a flow

Edit:
Found the thing I was looking for...

`
<http:connector name="NoSessionConnector">
      
       <service-overrides sessionHandler="org.mule.session.NullSessionHandler"/>

 </http:connector>

`

found here under 'HTTP Response Header'

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/HTTP+Transport+Reference

Or, you can also create a custom SessionHandler

Comment: Hey Rondo, I'm actually running into this issue right now.  I'm now looking for exactly what you reference, 'a mitigation strategy' for session variables that get sent out as headers in http calls.  I was just about to post a second question on stackoverflow for this reason.